# Dynamically increase box size in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a way to dynamically increase the size of a box in Crystal Report?

I have an investigation box which can contain lots of detail and i need this to increase in size when there is lots of text. The Root Cause description box should dynamically show after the the text has finished. The layout should be below.

Currently, the text is overflowing and going over each section making it hard to read.

All the boxes are in the Report Header section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place each box in a separate section (RHa, RHb, RHc, etc.).
To create multiple Report Header sections, right-click and select 'Insert Section Below'.